# create bar graph in seaborn to compare

Tags: python, seaborn

i want to know how to answer this here is the dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/emilianito/saheart

here is the question pls give the answer
Draw a bar plot to show the number of persons hvaing CHD or not in comparison to they having family history of the disease or not.

if possible pls use seaborn:)

i created pandas crosstab and tried to do it but this happens:-

code:

```
famhist_chd_comparison = pd.crosstab(sa_heart_df['famhist'], sa_heart_df['chd'])
sn.barplot(x = 'famhist', y = 'chd', data = famhist_chd_comparison)
```

the error is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-93-5b5be9a908a8> in <module>()
  1 famhist_chd_comparison = pd.crosstab(sa_heart_df['famhist'], sa_heart_df['chd'])
  ----> 2 sn.barplot(x = 'famhist', y = 'chd', data = famhist_chd_comparison)

usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/seaborn/_decorators.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
 44             )
 45         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
 ---> 46         return f(**kwargs)
 47     return inner_f
 48 

usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/seaborn/categorical.py in barplot(x, y, hue, 
data, order, hue_order, estimator, ci, n_boot, units, seed, orient, color, palette, 
saturation, errcolor, errwidth, capsize, dodge, ax, **kwargs)
3183                           estimator, ci, n_boot, units, seed,
3184                           orient, color, palette, saturation,
-> 3185                           errcolor, errwidth, capsize, dodge)
3186 
3187     if ax is None:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/seaborn/categorical.py in __init__(self, x, y, 
hue, data, order, hue_order, estimator, ci, n_boot, units, seed, orient, color, 
palette, saturation, errcolor, errwidth, capsize, dodge)
1583         """Initialize the plotter."""
1584         self.establish_variables(x, y, hue, data, orient,
-> 1585                                  order, hue_order, units)
1586         self.establish_colors(color, palette, saturation)
1587         self.estimate_statistic(estimator, ci, n_boot, seed)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/seaborn/categorical.py in 
establish_variables(self, x, y, hue, data, orient, order, hue_order, units)
151                 if isinstance(var, str):
152                     err = "Could not interpret input '{}'".format(var)
--> 153                     raise ValueError(err)
154 
155             # Figure out the plotting orientation

ValueError: Could not interpret input 'famhist'
```

Comment: Have you checked that `famhist_chd_comparison` contains a column `famhist`?

Comment: It should be `famhist_chd_comparison.plot(kind='bar')`. `pd.crosstab` converts the two columns to a wide form, where `famhist` is now on the index. `sns.barplot` expects the dataframe in long form. Use `sns.countplot(x='famhist', hue='chd', data=sa_heart_df)`